# Move elements out of sublists into new list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that holds several sublist, each one of them with a given number of elements inside. I need to move all elements inside all sublists into another list, ie: remove the separation among elements imposed by the sublists.

This is a MWE if what I mean:

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]], [[17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24]], [[25, 26, 27, 28], [26, 30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35, 36]]]

b = []
    for elem in a:
        for item in elem:
            b.append(item)
```

which results in:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28], [26, 30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35, 36]]
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant and simpler way to do this in python.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(a))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28], [26, 30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35, 36]]
```

[Timing comparison:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python#408281)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[item for sublist in a for item in sublist]
```

Comment: This works perfectly but I marked the other answer as accepted because,as the author stated, it is much faster. Thanks you very much!